# Why does ReplaceAll behave so oddly?

Tags: replacement

`ReplaceAll` can behave a bit oddly. Consider

```
(-1)^(1 + n)*Gamma[2 + n] /. {Gamma[s_] :> (s - 1)!, -((-1)^(a_)*(b_)) :> (-1)^(a + 1)*b}
(*(-1)^(1 + n) Gamma[2 + n]*)
```

Nothing is changed.
But

```
(-1)^(1 + n)*Gamma[2 + n] /. {Gamma[s_] :> (s - 1)!, -(-1)^(a_) :> Times[(-1)^(a + 1)]}

(*(-1)^(1 + n) (1 + n)!*)
```

`Gamma[2 + n]` is transformed into `(1 + n)!`.

What's the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first line in the details section in the documentation for [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

> `ReplaceAll` looks at each part of `expr`, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of `expr`. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts."

Basically what's happening is since `ReplaceAll` tries all rules in a top down fashion, your

```
-((-1)^(a_)*(b_)) :> (-1)^(a + 1)*b
```

rule is applied at the very beginning, and then `ReplaceAll` terminates since that rule was applied to the entire expression and *"The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts."*

A way around this is to exploit the `Flat` attribute of `Times`, just like you did in your second line of code.

**Edit:** Another thing I forgot to mention is your second pattern evaluates:

```
-((-1)^(a_)*(b_))
```

> ```
> (-1)^(1 + a_) b_
> ```

So really what you're saying is

```
(-1)^(1 + n)*Gamma[2 + n] /. {
  Gamma[s_] :> (s - 1)!, (-1)^(a_ + 1) b_ :> (-1)^(a + 1)*b
}
```

which is not what you want. So because `-(-1)^x` *auto-evaluates* to `(-1)^(x+1)`, your second rule serves no purpose and can be removed!

Comment: I have wished for many years the detailed documentation for ReplaceAll would elaborate more precisely what "a part" is. Yes if you think you know what it does then you may think it is obvious. If you don't think you know then you might wonder whether this is first try each atom (to use really old school LISP terminology), then every sublist, and finally the complete expression? Or in some other order? Is the order always precisely the same? I'd really like to find a reference that precisely documents this process. Thanks

Comment: +1, nice explanation. I've yet to find a case where MMA behaves "oddly" w/r to pattern transformations - perhaps my Lisp/Term-rewriting background, but the few times I *thought* something odd turned out to be my blinders. @bill & @WateSoyan: When in doubt, avail yourself of MMA facilities like `Trace` to see under the covers. Even simpler and quite effective: Put a compound statement with a leading `Print` or `Sow` on the RHS of the rule in question...

Comment: Yeah,it's certainly a good explanation since I never know it before.Hey,guy,how could you discover it?

Comment: @Chip Hurst Do ReplaceRepeated and ReplaceAll behave similarly?

Comment: @ciao Your suggestion is useful.Since Trace can't help in this case,Print just reflects which rule is used!

Comment: @ciao I am impressed that you have never had a problem writing a pattern trying to match radicals, denominators, complex numbers, minus signs and found it didn't match until you pretty much pasted the literal FullForm to make it happy. But it is easy to blame ourselves for mistakes. I have used Trace and then tried to control the forest of output with conditions on the tracing.

Comment: @WateSoyan yes `ReplaceRepeated` is essentially "keep applying `ReplaceAll` until it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Bill `ReplaceAll` acts in a top down fashion, looking at subexpression then head. You can see this by running `a[b[c, d[e]], f[g, h[i, j]]] /. {v_ /; (Print[v]; False) -> Null}`.